# Chrome crashes on pressing Enter key in web page for drop-down

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, crash

Chrome crashes on pressing Enter key in web page for drop-down. Working fine in Chrome 73 version but not in Chrome 74X versions.

Comment: any suspected code ? anything to look into ? many sherlocks waiting here for any clue.

Comment: Report a bug. You also need to be very specific - which dropdown on which page? Include enough information for someone to easily reproduce the problem.

Comment: @AnandSingh no suspected code . It is working in Chrome 73 versions means it would be browser issue..

Comment: @Tass it's happening for a particular window in my web application. Other window's working fine

Comment: Why is this tagged with ‘java’?  Does the web page contain an applet?

Comment: @VGR web page doesn't contain applet.

Comment: The Chrome team won't find bugs you talk about here. If it's really a bug, you need to report it to them: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95315?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en

Comment: If you want the bug fixed, you need to be very specific about what is on the web page, or even better a web page you can link to which they can easily try, steps that you took, exactly what "crash" means, etc.

Comment: The problem was occurring because on-click two function were called so 100 millisecond timeout added to resolve issue. thank you everyone :-)